# Call a fragment by itself in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I have a Fragment in which i am sending a HTTP request to get the data and show the data on the page.After that on click of button i want to refresh this fragment.I means to say that again on click of the button i want to send the  HTTP request to get the new data from the server and show that data into the fragment .

here is my **Button on click**

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

**FragmentCall**

```
fragTran.replace(R.id.content_frame, mainFrag);
fragTran.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
fragTran.addToBackStack(null);
fragTran.commit();
```

This is how we used to call the Fragments is this a right way to do this

After dismissing the dialog i want to call again the same Fragment .

Comment: you can have a menu item to do so....... why don't you give it a try

Comment: i am not getting you @NitinMisra will u please eleborate more

Comment: do you want same fragment with different data ?

Comment: yes @Sarkar i have to just send again the http request to get the fresh data from the server

Comment: @GauravPandey fragment is attached to the activity. you don't call fragments. You can make http request. Check if fragment is still attached have a method that makes http request and call that method

Comment: @Raghunandan i am trying your way .i think this will be the best way i have the function of httprequest

Comment: @Raghunandan but the records are getting append in the previous result

Comment: @GauravPandey what records are you talking about. Are you adding previous results + new result or does your http request return only new results. That is for you take care and by the way your question is very unclear

Comment: @Raghunandan first time what data i am showing on the fragment and after click of the button the updated records i am getting from the server it is getting append .Example first time 10 records after on click the records are 20 on the page

Comment: @GauravPandey that has nothing to do with the http request i guess. Its the way you are showing the data. By the way cache the result so avoid network operation often.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49033/discussion-between-gaurav-pandey-and-raghunandan)

Answer (score 2):

So you want same Fragment with new data. 
Lets assume you are having new data in an object of class named MyData

Now what you can do is, reload your fragment on data received. where reloading means setting the data again.

Case : you got the data outside the fragment. How to refresh fragment with that data

Step-1 :Keep the fragment instance available to your activity .

Step 2 : create a method relaodFragment as given below [in your fragment] .

```
 public void reloadFragment(MyData data) {
        if (data != null) {
            //reload your views with new data. using setters of all views.

      }
}
```

step 3 : call this method everytime you feel you are having new data.

CASE 2 : Data Retrieved on Same Fragment :

Make you implementation like this :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
      MyData data =gson.fromJson(getDataFromServer(param1, param2), MyData.class);
         populateViewsWithData(data);

}

public void populateViewsWithData(MyData data)
{

    // set data to views ..............
}


    public String  getDataFromServer(String param1,String param2)
    {

        // your logic to retrive data ... this method returns JSON you want to work with .. 
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


        Gson gson = new Gson();
         MyData data =gson.fromJson(getDataFromServer(param1, param2), MyData.class);
         populateViewsWithData(data);
         // congrates!.. fragment is reloaded again............

    }
```

Comment: onCreateView i am sending a Http request to get the data

Comment: so on button click you want to send the req. again. is it all you want ?

Comment: answer edited #Gaurav panday .  Case 2 is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

write this (`setHasOptionsMenu(true);`) in your `onCreateView();`

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.refresh_menu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_refresh) {
            REFRESH YOUR JSON
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call a same fragment in a new way. Instead you can refresh the view by loading the new data. The [PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/tree/master/library/src/com/handmark/pulltorefresh/library) library designed for such requirements that you can call the api again and refresh your view. This library works not only for `listview` but also views includes  `GridView, ScrollView and WebView`